# Получение пути к выбранному файлу

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, пути

Есть небольшая программа, которая выдает путь к выбранному файлу через OpenFileDialog...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string str = dialog.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}
```

Идея вот в чем, запускать тот или иной файл данной программой, которая будет выдавать полный путь запускаемого файла...

Или хотелось бы узнать на чем можно написать подобную программу или может есть готовые решения данного решения...

Comment: Так не сработает, нужно наоборот - кидать открываемый файл на программу, а в программе просто проверяйте параметры командной строки

Comment: А конкретней можно?

Comment: Поконкретнее какую часть комментария?

Comment: Вы написали что будет работать если не программу на файл кидать, а нужный нам файл на программу, вот как это должно работать и как проверять параметры командной строки, просто хотелось бы чтобы сама как такова запущенная программа не видна для клиента, а просто выводило диалоговое окно с определенным текстом и закрывалась по закрытию диалогового окна

Comment: Ну так не показывайте окно вообще, откройте `Program.cs` и напишите там нужную логику. Параметры можно получить из `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`, проверяйте и если там есть путь к файлу - сразу выводите MessageBox или типа того и закрывайте приложение, если параметров нет - показывайте окно (ну или как хотите, ва виднее)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри в сторону
    `Path.GetDirectoryName(myFile.FileName)`

Comment: Можете пояснить как это поможет в данной ситуации и при чем здесь директория?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]